# C++ Vignere Cipher Outputting Correctly Sometimes

Tags: c++, logic

Been trying to bug fix this for hours and cannot figure out how to fix it PLEASE HELP ME. It keeps returning randomly wrong characters when trying to decode.

```
string removeNonAlphas(string original) {
    string result;
    for (char c : original) { // cylces through each position in original
        if (isalpha(c)) {   // checks if c is an alphabetical character
            result += c;    // adds c to result if it is an alphabetical character
        }
    }
    return result;
}

char shiftAlphaCharacter(char c, int n) {
    if (islower(c)) {
        return 'a' + (c - 'a' + n) % 26;
    }
    else if (isupper(c)) {
        return 'A' + (c - 'A' + n) % 26;
    }
    // return the character itself if it is not a letter
    return c;

}

string caesarCipher(string original, int key, bool encrypt) {
    string result = "";
    if (!encrypt) {
        key = -key;
    }
    for (char c : original) {
        result += shiftAlphaCharacter(c, key);
    }

    return result;
}

string vigenereCipher(string original, string keyword, bool encrypt) {
    string result = ""; // final string to add to later
    keyword = removeNonAlphas(keyword); // stripping all non alphabetical characters
    int keywordLength = keyword.length(); // getting the length of the keyword
    int j = 0;
    for (char c : original) { //running for each character in the inputed string c = current character
        if (isalpha(c)) { // checking if the character in the inputed string is a letter that can be cyphered
            int key;
            if (isupper(keyword[j % keywordLength])) {
                key = keyword[j % keywordLength] - 'A';
                /* Determine the shift value based on the current character of the keyword
                   Adjust the shift value to be in the range of 0 to 25 for both uppercase and lowercase letters */
                
                
                
            }
            else {
                key = keyword[j % keywordLength] - 'a';
            }
            result += caesarCipher(string(1, c), key, encrypt); // Apply the Caesar cipher to the current character and add it to the result string
            j++; // move to the next character in keyword
        }
        else {
            result += c; // if the character isn't a letter just add it to result and move on
        }
    }
    return result;


}
```

I think it is something wrong with vigenereCipher but honestly it is really hard to tell the exact problem even with the debugger any help would be greatly appreciated T_T

I've tried changing editing both vigenereCipher and shiftAlphaCharacter but d and b still ended up X and Y.

Comment: Instead of `key = -key` try `key = 26-key`.